# Python decoding issue with hashlib.digest() method

Tags: python, google-app-engine, decode

Hello StackOverflow community,

Using Google App Engine, I wrote a keyToSha256() method within a model class (extending db.Model) :

```
class Car(db.Model):
    def keyToSha256(self):
        keyhash = hashlib.sha256(str(self.key())).digest()
        return keyhash
```

When displaying the output (ultimately within a Django template), I get garbled text, for example :

> �����_ɘ�!`�I�!�;�QeqN��Al�'2

I was expecting something more in line with this :

> 9f86d081884c7d659a2feaa0c55ad015a3bf4f1b2b0b822cd15d6c15b0f00a08

Am I missing something important ? Despite reading several guides on ASCII, Unicode, utf-8 and the like, I think I'm still far from mastering the secrets of string encoding/decoding. After browsing StackOverflow and searching for insights via Google, I figured out I should ask the question here. Any idea ? Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.hexdigest()` instead.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks Ignacio ! I just read http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html#hashlib.hash.hexdigest : I can't understand why .digest() won't do the trick, though. Strings are so mysterious to me.

Comment: `.digest()` does give you a string, but it's the raw bytes.

Comment: Great, I understand perfectly ! Python doc was misleading for an inexperienced programmer like me, but reading it one more time with your answer in mind makes it a lot easier to understand. I now get the meaning of "non-binary environments", which I'm pretty sure will be helpful in the future.

Comment: I'm amazed how many people think the output of hash functions such as SHA1 are hex strings. No offense intended to the OP - it's a common misconception.